# Почему не видно R.java в проекте?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Добрый день. В Android Studio работаю недавно.
Скажите, пожалуйста, почему программа не может распознать, где находится класс R? C чем может быть связана данная проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Много с чем, часто из-за ошибки в `.xml` файле. Мало информации. В чистом проекте все видит? Что предшествовало этому?

Comment: import правильный для него?

Comment: В чистом да, видит.
Этот проект скачан с developer.android.com, как учебное приложение.

Что предшествовало. 
Вот тут сейчас будет жесть с моей стороны.
Я его скачала, но в AndroidStudio сделала новый проект и брала файлы из скаченного.
Я хотела разобраться, как он устроен, но чет не работает теперь :)

Comment: Ну в этом и проблема :) Откройте проект, который скачали и разбирайтесь в нем.
Если же хотите переносить - смотрите чтобы были прописаны все импорты, если что необходимо - прописано в `AndroidManifest`, были нужные `xml` файлы и пр.

Comment: build->clean project; build->rebuild project

Comment: Я разобралась! 
Я изменила имя пакета у скаченных файлов. 
Надо почистить кэш в системе.
В AndroidStudio File->InvalidateCahces помогло.
Правда, у меня теперь другая проблема, и о ней я смогу написать только через 40 минут из-за ограничений на сайте.
В любом случае спасибо, ребята! :)

Comment: @ЕленаТеплякова, т.е. ответ из предложенного вопроса - дубликата помог?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да. 
От меня что-то требуется кроме нажатия большой синий кнопки в начале страницы?

Comment: @VAndrJ, рубрика глупых вопросов.
А что означает фраза "смотрите чтобы были прописаны все импорты"?
Можете не расписывать здесь, а просто дать ссылку, что нужно почитать или "как правильно загуглить", я сама разберусь.

Comment: @ЕленаТеплякова, уже нет, я сам как дубль отметил)

Comment: @ЕленаТеплякова, чтобы использовать к-л класс его надо импортировать в файл. В скаченном вами проекте могут использоваться классы из сторонних библиотек и студия не сможет их импортнуть автоматом если библиотека не подключена к проекту.

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ, оперативно)) 
а VAndrJ мой комментарий теперь не увидит?

Comment: @ЕленаТеплякова, увидит)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Если это, то стороннюю библиотеку я подключила из jar. Не факт, что правильно, но подключила) Больше не буду флудить, а то меня уже просят пройти в чат))